# black background image after i resize and upload using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

hello i have created an upload form which i have also implemented a image resize script using php

my upload works, but the issue i have is after resize and upload i am getting a black background , please see below

[image]

[image]

this is how is what i am using presently to upload and resize my images,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['products']))
{
include("resize.php");

$random1 = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

 $target = "k/";  $target = $target .$random1.basename( $_FILES['product']['name']);

            // $pic="uploads/".$random1.$_FILES['product']['name'];
             $pics= "k/".$_FILES['product']['name'];

             echo $target;
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product']['tmp_name'], $target)) 


{

    // *** 1) Initialise / load image
    $resizeObj = new resize($target);

    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(300, 300, 'crop');

    // *** 3) Save image
    $resizeObj -> saveImage('k/sample-resizedasr.jpg', 1000);
    }
     }

    ?>

    <form action="up.php" id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label>Picture<input name="product" type="file" id="upload" size="10" required="required"/></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="products" value="ddd" />
    <button class="tran3s">Create Property</button>
                            </form>
```

and my class

```
<?php

 # ========================================================================#
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   # ========================================================================#


        class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                   $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

please any help on this , how can i make the image display properly

Comment: does your original image have a transparent background?

Comment: the one which is totally blank didnt have while the other which shows a black bg behind the image had

Comment: imagecreatetruecolor creates a black image so any transparency will be replaced by black. I'm not sure about the blank image, was it blank to begin with? Perhaps it did not upload correctly, the code uses @ in front of imagecreatefromjpeg etc so any errors will be missed.

Comment: so what should i use

Comment: try adding `imagealphablending ($this->imageResized, false)` after creating the image with `imagecreatetruecolor `. if that fixes it i'll add it as an answer. :)

Comment: do you want to just resize or crop?

Comment: both, would be better

Comment: cropping calls another function which then creates the same problem. I'd suggest adding a class property to set whether transparency should be maintained and adding a private function to replace all calls to `imagecreatetruecolor`.

Comment: ok cool, but hw do i do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145259/discussion-between-inarilo-and-tee-famakin).

Comment: You can use Image Intervention Package, This package have backup() function. Backup can do background to black...
[Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/api/backup)